# How install Ubuntu on old Compaq notebook?

Tags: system-installation

I have an old Compaq notebook. I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.

The notebook has these specs:

1. AMD Athlon CPU
2. 30 GB HD
3. 512 MB memory
4. 14" screen

Can I install on this notebook? The notebook now has Windows XP, but I don't need to keep it.

The notebook has CD and USB, is using USB faster?

Comment: You can use a CD or a USB to install, I think.  Either method works.

Comment: You can, but it vill be slow. You might have a problem with the installation, but the alternative installation would work.
I do think you should check the alternatives mentioned here, or add more RAM if you can.

Comment: Some older machines won't boot from USB, so downloading the ISO and burning the CD-R is the Sure Thing.  Here's the big question: What do you want to do with it? If just surf the web, play music or video and occasionally write something or use a spreadsheet, I'd go with Lubuntu  http://www.lubuntu.net/ and http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=lubuntu will provide more info.

Comment: If your machine can't boot from USB, or DVD, and the ISO is to big to fit on a CD, you can try this [Method](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux/340171#340171).

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed Ubuntu on a machine that has less specifications than yours, and it works.  It's slow, but works.  If you don't mind the system being slow, then its OK.  Otherwise I would seriously get a diffrent machine, or if that's not a option upgrade atleast the RAM in yours.

As far as CD or USB?  I would use USB.

If you're still wanting to do it, then [See this site](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

Answer (score 1):

I would not try and install Ubuntu on that machine - unless you want to upgrade the RAM.

I would install Xubuntu. Though you could try Lubuntu - it uses less resources than Xubuntu.

Yes you can use a USB to install with assuming that the notebook will boot from it, you can use unetbootin to do that.

If you do not need the XP on the notebook - when you boot the installer then use the Whole Disk option.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing download the ISO and then  make a bootable USB using unetbootin. you can find the unetbootin if you google it up. Making a Bootable USB is better as you can perform the installation faster as CD's are always slower than USB.

Also since you  have ram,I suggest you to use  LXDE as desktop enviornment,It will give a new life to your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your computer is too slow to run Ubuntu. I think that even if you try Lubuntu, it might be too heavy for your machine but you might try.

You might opt for some other lightweight Linux distribution like Puppy linux for example.

It all depends what you want to use the laptop for.